# Whatsapp Api-WART Registration

Tags: api, whatsapp

i have downloaded whatsapp api,and i am trying to register in WART i get the ID but When i click on Request Code i get the error saying "could not request code using either sms or voice".reason:old_version.Anyone have any idea what to do?
i have already checked this links below.
http://www.wahelper.com/register-whatsapp-account-tool.html 
https://github.com/mgp25/WART 
https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsApp-Registration-Flow

Comment: did you manage to get your WhatsApp password another way?

Answer (score 2):

Whatsapp [drop support for old phones](https://blog.whatsapp.com/10000617/WhatsApp-support-for-mobile-devices?l=en), and this API was based on those phones protocols